# ¿Cuál es la utilidad de SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

¿Para qué sirve `SharedPreferences` en Android? Tengo un ejemplo sobre este funcionamiento y lo probé en Android Studio, pero me gustaría saber por qué arroja *3* como resultado y para qué sirve.

```java
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences( "MyPref" ,
    MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString( "1" , "2" );
editor.putString( "3" , "4" );
editor.commit();
String number = pref.getString( "2" , "3" );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared preferences te permite guardar datos en formato (clave, valor).  El método getString() toma como primer argumento la clave que se quiere recuperar y como segundo parámetro el valor por defecto en caso no se encuentre la clave. En tu ejemplo `String number = pref.getString( "2" , "3" );` retorna el valor por defecto 3 ya que la clave 2 no existe, solo existen las claves 1 y 3.

Comment: excelente, gracias por la respuesta :D